# PHP fatal error referencing a filepath and file that doesn't exist

Tags: caching, joomla2.5, php, dreamhost

I'm developing a website that's getting the following error code:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1439957 bytes) in /home/user/domain.com/libraries/joomla/cache/controller.php on line 224
```

Now, I might be reading this wrong but it's telling me it tried to allocate LESS than the allowed memory size, so I'm not sure how it was exhausted to begin with.

Here is the crux of the problem. I am coding this site in Joomla. I tried to enable caching on the Joomla installation, specifically **Progressive Caching**. It started generating this error, so I disabled it. Now I can't get rid of this error!

I'm assuming the error itself is due to the fact that I'm hosting this site from a standard shared server on Dreamhost, but I can't understand why, after disabling the caching, I'm still getting this error for a file that now no longer exists on the FTP.

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your script is trying use more than 90MB which is probably the process limit set in php.ini. Dreamhost allows you to use a custom php.ini file in which you can increase your process limit. From experience Dreamhost allows each shared account to use just under 512MB per account of system memory before they start killing processes so you should be able to up that limit a fair bit.

memory_limit = 128M to your php.ini file

instructions
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHP.ini

or you can set it in the individual php script.

ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');